# Return matrix out of index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a yearly index and want to calculate a matrix of returns for every combinations of years. The start year (2000) is tarted as the starting value.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004],
                   'Value': [100, 105, 110, 120, 107]},
                    index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I am currently able to to this in a list of lists setting, I wonder if there is a more pyhtonic approach?

```
value = 100.00
return_list = []
years = df["year"].tolist()
df_len = len(years) - 1
for index, row in df[1:].iterrows():
    year = row["year"]
    df[year] = df["Value"] / value - 1
    returns = df[year].tolist()
    if len(returns) < df_len:
        dif = df_len - len(returns)
        returns = dif * [0] + returns
    else:
        returns = returns[1:]
    return_list.append(returns)
    value = row["Value"]
    df = df[df["year"] > year]

df = pd.DataFrame(return_list, columns=years[1:])
df = df.set_index(df.columns)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like every value in your 'Value' column, divided by every other value, then subtracting 1. You can do this using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

a = df['Value'].to_numpy()
vals = (a / a[:, None]) - 1
```

If you're only interested in the upper triangle (as is the case in your example), you can do:

```
vals = np.triu(vals)
```

You can then create a DataFrame from your new numpy array:

```
results = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=df['year'], index=df['year'])
```

Giving:

```
year  2000  2001      2002      2003      2004
year                                          
2000   0.0  0.05  0.100000  0.200000  0.070000
2001   0.0  0.00  0.047619  0.142857  0.019048
2002   0.0  0.00  0.000000  0.090909 -0.027273
2003   0.0  0.00  0.000000  0.000000 -0.108333
2004   0.0  0.00  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

I think the hardest part of this to understand is the line:

```
vals = (a / a[:, None]) - 1
```

It is worth reading up on numpy [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to understand what's going on here.